# How to update installed lsp servers in lsp-mode

Tags: lsp-mode

I have installed the javascript-typescript and the eslint language servers using the `lsp-install-server` command. I want to make sure I'm using the latest version. Doing `lsp-install-server` again doesn't show neither the typescript nor the eslint servers I just installed, I guess it is because it only shows the uninstalled servers.

Is there a command or an recommended approach to update the servers?

I guess I can delete the installed servers folders and do the install again but it doesn't seem right since I used a command for installing there should probably be a command for updating.

lsp-mode config:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :straight t
  :hook ((js-mode typescript-mode) . lsp-deferred)
  :custom
  (lsp-enable-snippet nil)
  :config
  (setq read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an interactive function called `lsp-update-server`. You can of course update the server packages manually independent of `lsp`.

Comment: oh, I couldn't find the function and didn't think of updating the lsp package because I do it very often, but alas, the function does exist, must have been added recently. Thanks (added here https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/pull/3160)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming here for **Java** (jdt.ls) should check the server download url defined as customizable variable `lsp-java-jdt-download-url` and pick a package from https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/ . Be sure to look carefully through the list as it is not sorted by increasing version numbers.

To see if the new version is active, check the Emacs buffer `*lsp-log*` and search for `Initializing Java Language Server ...` which provides the version.